# Mongodb, PHP and Javascript - Graphs, Charts, Data Display

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb, graph, charts

I am wondering if there is a simple way to create charts/graphs within Mongodb, php and javascript.  I want to be able to display graphs on my website of the data in my mongodb using PHP and/or javascript.

For example: lets say i had a mongodb with a collection called "sales" and i want to display the average sales in a graph group by month.

I am assuming i would have to use some sort of map-reduce to group the data then somehow  display it in a graph on my page using php and/or javascript.

I don't have any idea how to do this because i am new to mongodb.  Can someone please point me in the right directions?  Also i would love if there was some sort of plug-in, framework, library or api to accomplish this (time saver).  If not, i don't mind learning how to code all of this if someone can just point me in the right direction (books, websites, videos, resources, etc.).

Thank you.

Comment: I wish if people were going to vote your question down they would at least put an explanation.  Many of us our newbies and that's why we use this site.  If you're going to vote a q down leave a remark as to why.  #cowards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what your looking for...

http://www.amcharts.com/

It's a javascript library that helps you make charts and graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net)

pChart is a PHP class oriented framework designed to create aliased charts.